# OT COBOL, anyone? External symbol 'hcobol_cvt_str2bnum' not found

Tags: cobol, symbols

I'm not too familiar with the language or the environment. Does anyone know what could be causing this and a possible remedy? I'm not using any other libraries other than what came with the OTCOBOL distro. I even rebuilt OTCOBOL and recompiled. Still getting this error.

I've tried compile, make, and build from the IDE as well as from the command line.

As requested, here is a link to OTCOBOL:
http://www.tim-r-norton.com/images/otcobolz.exe

Comment: I'm trying to compile some sample code, but have never encountered this with my own COBOL programs, albeit only a few.

Comment: I just dropped a completely fresh OTCOBOL install into my virtual machine. The sample code compiles just fine now. Still would like to know what may have caused the error above.

Comment: Post a link to the compiler site. I don't recognize it either.

Comment: It is a free compiler, no longer supported since 1998!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognise the name OTCOBOL, but the error seems to imply a conversion from string to binary has failed. Is this a compile or run-time error?

Comment: Good call. I noticed the problem crop back up once more. I wonder if something wasn't implemented properly. The code has no calls or dependencies on anything unusual. And indeed, it is a compile-time error.